# How to permanently edit a list in Python 3

Tags: python, list, append

How can I make it so that when a user gives input to append something to a list it is permanent, since when I close my program that modification is gone

Comment: You have to save it to a file, and read it from a file.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: "“Nothing is permanent”-- Dalai Lama

Comment: You can go for some database. I would prefer `mongo DB`. We can able to store array objects in a mongo db collection.

Answer (score 0):

Lists by definition are mutable, meaning they can easily be changed. Anything like dictionaries, sets, tuples, and lists all leave the computer memory after the code is finished. Writing your information to some sort of file is one way you can save information to retrieve later. Of course that still isn't 'permanent' but it lasts longer than the time your code runs.

In my example, I am appending to the end of a text file. Every time the user enters another input, it will add to the end of this file. In later runs of the code, the changes from past runs will still be active.

```
def write_to_file():
    with open("file.txt", "a") as f:
        user_input = input("Input a value: ")
        f.write(f"{user_input}\n")


def read_from_file():
    with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        target_line = int(input("Select a line to read: "))
        lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines[target_line].strip("\n"))


while True:
    write_to_file()
    if input("Would you like to input another value? ").upper() not in ("Y", "YES"):
        break
while True:
    read_from_file()
    if input("Would you like to retrieve another value? ").upper() not in ("Y", "YES"):
        break
```